# NETLOGO patches squares and rectangles

Tags: netlogo

I'm attempting to make squares and rectangles with patches on netlogo, with the variables x (pxcor) y (pycor) w (width) l (length). I wrote

```
ask patch random w random h [set pcolor blue]
```

and was able to create regular rectangles and squares with lengths and widths I enter, but they always appear with the lower left corner at 0, 0. How can I create these shapes and have them appear with the upper left corner the x and y coordinates that I enter. Please, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your code instructs NetLogo to turn ONE patch blue, not a rectangle of patches. This is because `random w` selects a random number from 0 to (w-1) and `random h` selects a random number from 0 to (h-1). If the two random numbers chosen happen to be 3 and 2, you are telling NetLogo to change the color of `patch 3 2` to blue.

If you are actually getting rectangles, you must be repeatedly selecting one random patch, but that's not in the code you provided.

In NetLogo, patch 0 0 is the centre of the world (though that can be changed with settings). Think about what you are trying to do. If you want (0,0) to be the upper left corner, then you want the rectangle to cover the space from `pxcor` of 0 to w and `pycor` of -h to 0 (possibly different, depending on whether you want 0,0 in the rectangle).

So you want something more like:

```
ask patches with [pxcor <= 3 and pxcor > 0 and pycor < 0 and pycor >= -2]
[ set pcolor blue ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help- now I know how to get the upper left corner to e changed. I tried using ask patches with [pxcor <= (w - 1) and pxcor >= x and pycor <= y and pycor >= (- h + 1)]
[ set pcolor blue ] but  when i replace x and y for the numbers, it does not work. ask patches with [pxcor <= (w - 1) and pxcor >= 0 and pycor <= 0 and pycor >= (- h + 1)]
[ set pcolor blue ] work, but using a variable does not. Any advice? This function is a helper by the way, the actual one has the coordinates and w and h as numbers.

Comment: Do a new question with more complete code. The description of your problem should report any error messages, what you want to occur, and what actually occurs. All relevant code must be included if you want us to work out what's wrong.

Comment: I have asked a new question on the site any chance you could offer some more help?